# How to select values that exist in one table but no in another?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to know how to find the names (namn) of the people who have taught on a course (kkod) but have never been course coordinator (kansv). Is it a minus operation (not exists operation)? 
The result should look like:

```
namn
Jonas
Marie
Rikard
Urban
```

The results above should be retrieved from the two following tables:
table tf;

```
kkod                            termin           kansv       antal
------------------------------  ---------------  ----------  ----------
TIG015                          ht2010           Kalle       90
TIG015                          ht2011           Kalle       90
TIG015                          ht2012           Kalle       85
TIG015                          ht2013           Kalle       88
TIG015                          ht2014           Magnus      110
TIG015                          ht2015           Aida        100
TIG162                          ht2010           Kjell       90
TIG162                          ht2011           Kjell       85
TIG162                          ht2012           Kjell       85
TIG162                          ht2014           Lisen       110
TIG058                          ht2010           Janne       80
TIG058                          ht2012           Lennart     80
TIG058                          ht2015           Lennart     80
TIG058                          ht2016           Alan        85
TIG059                          vt2012           Janne       75
TIA008                          vt2015           Aida        35
TIG059                          vt2013           Dina        75
TIG059                          vt2014           Janne       75
TIG098                          ht2015           Agneta      60
TIG016                          ht2011           Janne       80
TIG016                          ht2012           Maria       80
TIG016                          ht2015           Maria       80
TIG016                          vt2012           Maria       75
TIG163                          ht2011           Lennart     75
TIG163                          ht2012           Lennart     80
TIG163                          ht2014           Lennart     90
TIG163                          vt2012           Lennart     75
TIG164                          ht2010           Juha        70
TIG164                          ht2011           Alan        60
TIG164                          ht2012           Alan        55
TIG164                          ht2014           Alan        60
TIG164                          ht2015           Alan        75
TIG064                          ht2010           William     50
TIG064                          vt2012           William     80
TIG064                          vt2013           Faramarz    80
TIG064                          vt2014           Faramarz    66
TIG064                          vt2015           Faramarz    80
TIG064                          vt2016           Faramarz    55
TIG065                          vt2013           Kalle       25
TIG065                          vt2014           Kalle       23
TIG065                          vt2015           Kalle       19
TIG065                          vt2016           Kalle       25
TIG166                          ht2010           Fredrik     40
TIG167                          vt2012           Janne       20
TIG167                          vt2013           Janne       24
TIG167                          vt2014           Henrik      33
TIG167                          vt2015           Henrik      43
TIG167                          vt2016           Henrik      32
TIG165                          ht2011           William     80
TIG165                          ht2012           Alan        80
TIG165                          ht2014           Lennart     90
TIG067                          ht2009           Johan       70
TIA003                          ht2012           Dina        24
TIA003                          ht2013           Dina        26
TIA003                          ht2014           Dina        31
TIA003                          ht2015           Dina        18
TIG061                          ht2009           Lennart     85
TIG061                          ht2010           Lennart     65
TIG061                          vt2013           Lennart     35
TIG060                          vt2012           Fredrik     25
TIG063                          vt2012           Kjell       40
TIG063                          vt2013           Kjell       13
TIG063                          vt2014           Kjell       32
TIG063                          vt2015           Kjell       40
TIG063                          vt2016           Kjell       21
TIG066                          vt2012           Janne       60
TIG066                          vt2013           Janne       60
TIG066                          vt2014           Janne       56
TIG066                          vt2015           Janne       54
TIG066                          vt2016           Janne       80
TIA010                          ht2011           Juha        20
TIA004                          ht2015           Janne       75
TIA015                          ht2013           Maria       15
TIA019                          ht2016           Janne       25
```

and table uv;

```
kkod                            termin           namn
------------------------------  ---------------  ----------
TIG098                          ht2015           Agneta
TIG015                          ht2014           Aida
TIG015                          ht2015           Aida
TIG058                          ht2010           Alan
TIG058                          ht2012           Alan
TIG058                          ht2016           Alan
TIG059                          vt2014           Alan
TIG059                          vt2015           Alan
TIG059                          vt2016           Alan
TIG163                          ht2011           Alan
TIG163                          ht2012           Alan
TIG163                          vt2012           Alan
TIG164                          ht2010           Alan
TIG164                          ht2011           Alan
TIG164                          ht2012           Alan
TIG164                          ht2014           Alan
TIG164                          ht2015           Alan
TIG165                          ht2011           Alan
TIG165                          ht2012           Alan
TIG059                          vt2012           Dina
TIG059                          vt2013           Dina
TIG167                          vt2012           Dina
TIG163                          ht2011           Faramarz
TIG163                          vt2012           Faramarz
TIG163                          ht2012           Faramarz
TIG163                          ht2014           Faramarz
TIG060                          vt2012           Fredrik
TIG166                          ht2010           Fredrik
TIG061                          ht2010           Henrik
TIG061                          vt2013           Henrik
TIG167                          vt2014           Henrik
TIG167                          vt2015           Henrik
TIG167                          vt2016           Henrik
TIG065                          vt2014           Kalle
TIG065                          vt2015           Kalle
TIG065                          vt2016           Kalle
TIG065                          vt2014           Aida
TIG065                          vt2015           Aida
TIG065                          vt2016           Aida
TIA004                          ht2015           Janne
TIA019                          ht2016           Janne
TIG016                          ht2011           Janne
TIG016                          ht2012           Janne
TIG016                          ht2015           Janne
TIG016                          vt2012           Janne
TIG058                          ht2010           Janne
TIG059                          vt2012           Janne
TIG059                          vt2013           Janne
TIG059                          vt2014           Janne
TIG059                          vt2015           Janne
TIG059                          vt2016           Janne
TIG066                          vt2012           Janne
TIG066                          vt2013           Janne
TIG066                          vt2014           Janne
TIG066                          vt2015           Janne
TIG066                          vt2016           Janne
TIG163                          ht2011           Janne
TIG167                          vt2012           Janne
TIG067                          ht2009           Johan
TIG015                          ht2014           Jonas
TIG015                          ht2015           Jonas
TIA010                          ht2011           Juha
TIG060                          vt2012           Juha
TIG164                          ht2010           Juha
TIG164                          ht2011           Juha
TIG164                          ht2012           Juha
TIG166                          ht2010           Juha
TIA004                          ht2015           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2010           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2011           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2012           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2013           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2014           Kalle
TIG016                          ht2012           Kalle
TIG016                          ht2015           Kalle
TIG016                          vt2012           Kalle
TIG059                          vt2014           Kalle
TIG059                          vt2015           Kalle
TIG059                          vt2016           Kalle
TIG067                          ht2009           Kalle
TIG015                          ht2014           Kjell
TIG015                          ht2015           Kjell
TIG063                          vt2012           Kjell
TIG063                          vt2014           Kjell
TIG063                          vt2015           Kjell
TIG063                          vt2016           Kjell
TIG162                          ht2010           Kjell
TIG162                          ht2011           Kjell
TIG162                          ht2012           Kjell
TIG167                          vt2014           Kjell
TIG167                          vt2016           Kjell
TIA015                          ht2013           Lennart
TIG015                          ht2015           Lennart
TIA003                          ht2012           Dina
TIA003                          ht2013           Dina
TIA003                          ht2014           Dina
TIA003                          ht2015           Dina
TIA003                          ht2012           Aida
TIA003                          ht2013           Aida
TIA003                          ht2014           Aida
TIA003                          ht2015           Aida
TIA008                          vt2015           Aida
TIG058                          ht2012           Lennart
TIG058                          ht2015           Lennart
TIG059                          vt2014           Lennart
TIG059                          vt2015           Lennart
TIG059                          vt2016           Lennart
TIG061                          ht2010           Lennart
TIG061                          vt2013           Lennart
TIG162                          ht2012           Lennart
TIG163                          ht2011           Lennart
TIG163                          ht2012           Lennart
TIG163                          ht2014           Lennart
TIG163                          ht2015           Lennart
TIG163                          vt2012           Lennart
TIG165                          ht2011           Lennart
TIG165                          ht2012           Lennart
TIG165                          ht2014           Lennart
TIG165                          ht2015           Lennart
TIA019                          ht2016           Lisen
TIG098                          ht2015           Lisen
TIG162                          ht2012           Lisen
TIG162                          ht2014           Lisen
TIG162                          ht2015           Lisen
TIG015                          ht2014           Magnus
TIG067                          ht2009           Magnus
TIG015                          ht2015           Maria
TIG016                          ht2011           Maria
TIG016                          ht2012           Maria
TIG163                          ht2014           Maria
TIG163                          ht2015           Maria
TIA015                          ht2013           Marie
TIG165                          ht2014           Marie
TIG165                          ht2015           Marie
TIG167                          vt2015           Rikard
TIA019                          ht2016           Urban
TIG015                          ht2015           Urban
TIG064                          ht2010           William
TIG064                          vt2012           William
TIG064                          vt2013           William
TIG165                          ht2011           William
```

Appriciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLIte, you can use `except`:

```
select kanst as namn
from tf
except
select namn
from uv;
```

Alternatively:

```
select distinct kanst as namn
from tf
where not exists (select 1 from uv where uv.namn = tf.kanst);
```

Comment: Im however not getting any results when I put that into my cmd. Im using sqlite3 btw

Comment: I rearanged some of the attributes and table positions in the statement. Do you know of any method of how to use "not exist" in this case scenario? :)

Comment: And is the except operation like a not exist thingy almost?

Comment: oh actually since I want the result to show the names of the persons, I did "select namn as namn" instead of "select kansv as namn" hehehe :)